# How to find out whether iphone app is killed and relaunched again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

How will I know in appDidBecomeActive that 
1. app is launched from the background
2. app is killed and launched from menu again.

How can I differentiate between these two?

Comment: didBecomeActive will be called when app comes from background, it will not get caled when you killed the app and open it again. In your 2nd case didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will get called.

Comment: `didBecomeActive` is also called for many reasons while the app is running.

Comment: Both cases didBecomeActive is called. In 2nd case, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called and I have a boolean to know whether it is killed or not. I guess setting boolean in Appdelegate and checking it is not a good approach. That is the reason for posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an app is fully relaunched, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called. When returning from the background, `didEnterForeground` is called.

Keep in mind that `didBecomeActive` can be called in other cases besides those two. A system alert might appear while the user is using your app. When the alert is dismissed, your app becomes active again. And in this case it wasn't in the background and it wasn't relaunched.

The only way for `didBecomeActive` to know why it became active is to set a flag in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didEnterForeground` and check that value in `didBecomeActive`.

Comment: thanks mate. I have already done that, just got extra clarity on the cases the delegates called.. :)